# Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins when I run maven in VSTS

Tags: maven, azure-devops

I am running build from **VSTS Private agent** and I have maven installed in that private agent.But when I am running the build its failing with the below error.Please help me here.

**Error:**

> Scanning for projects... Downloading from central:
>   https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/3.0.0/maven-clean-plugin-3.0.0.pom
>   Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:3.0.0: Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:3.0.0 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
>   for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:3.0.0 Downloading
>   from central:
>   https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/2.4/maven-install-plugin-2.4.pom
>   Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4: Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
>   for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:jar:2.4 Downloading
>   from central:
>   https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.6/maven-resources-plugin-2.6.pom
>   Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6: Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
>   for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
>   Downloading from central:
>   https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/2.12.4/maven-surefire-plugin-2.12.4.pom
>   Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4: Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
>   for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:jar:2.12.4
>   Downloading from central:
>   https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/3.5.1/maven-compiler-plugin-3.5.1.pom
>   Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1: Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
>   for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.5.1
>   Downloading from central:
>   https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/2.4/maven-jar-plugin-2.4.pom
>   Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.4: Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.4 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
>   for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:jar:2.4 Downloading from
>   central:
>   https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/2.7/maven-deploy-plugin-2.7.pom
>   Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7: Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
>   for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:jar:2.7 Downloading
>   from central:
>   https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-site-plugin/3.3/maven-site-plugin-3.3.pom
>   Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3: Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
>   for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:jar:3.3 Downloading
>   from central:
>   https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/1.3/maven-antrun-plugin-1.3.pom
>   Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3: Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
>   for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:jar:1.3 Downloading
>   from central:
>   https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/2.2-beta-5/maven-assembly-plugin-2.2-beta-5.pom
>   Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5: Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5 or one of
>   its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact
>   descriptor for
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:jar:2.2-beta-5
>   Downloading from central:
>   https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/2.8/maven-dependency-plugin-2.8.pom
>   Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8: Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
>   for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:2.8
>   Downloading from central:
>   https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-release-plugin/2.3.2/maven-release-plugin-2.3.2.pom
>   Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.3.2: Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.3.2 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
>   for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:jar:2.3.2 Failed to
>   retrieve plugin descriptor for
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1: Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
>   for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.5.1 Failed to
>   retrieve plugin descriptor for
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:3.0.0: Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:3.0.0 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
>   for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:3.0.0 Downloading
>   from central:
>   https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
>   Downloading from central:
>   https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
>   Could not transfer metadata
>   org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from/to central
>   (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to
>   repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.44.215]
>   failed: Connection timed out: connect Could not transfer metadata
>   org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from/to central
>   (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to
>   repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.44.215]
>   failed: Connection timed out: connect Failure to transfer
>   org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from
>   https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
>   repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error:
>   Could not transfer metadata
>   org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from/to central
>   (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to
>   repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.44.215]
>   failed: Connection timed out: connect Failure to transfer
>   org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from
>   https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
>   repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error:
>   Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml
>   from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to
>   repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.44.215]
>   failed: Connection timed out: connect

Comment: What're tasks of your build definition? Do you refer to this article to add related tasks: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Extension+for+VSTS-TFS#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeExtensionforVSTS-TFS-AnalysingaJavaprojectwithMavenorGradle? What's the detail code of pom file?

Comment: @ starian chen-MSFT ,As you said,I have added prepare analysis  task and maven task and publish analysis result tasks.But here I am having doubt what is the maven goal in the maven task.I have pointed the pom.xml which is in my local sysem (Private agent).Please help here.

Comment: The maven task is used to build and test your java project.

Comment: @ starian chen-MSFT,When I add clean package task or only clean task its failing with the Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins .like I showed the log in the top.Please help here.

Comment: Can you share the detail log on the OneDrive?

Comment: @ starian chen-MSFT, Please find the complete log in Zip file. https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvMxvVJdKJlVhxyNHgVsd-0LrcAq  Please help me here.Only Running maven task and goals clean package or clean alone I tried.No luck.

Comment: What's the result if you build the project through maven command manually? Can you reproduce this issue with a new project?

Comment: @ starian chen-MSFT, When I run the same project locally through command prompt like this : mvn.cmd -f C:\agent\_work\1\s\Project\pom.xml package -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000/ -Dsonar.login=admin -Dsonar.password=admin -Dsonar.projectName=project -Dsonar.projectKey=Project -Dsonar.projectVersion=1.0 org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar...Its getting succeeded. The goal I passed here is org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar then only its working.If I give sonar:sonar as a goal its failing with different error.

Comment: Error if I run the sonar:sonar goal through command prompt:SonarQube: Fail to get bootstrap index from server: Status returned by url [http://hostname:9095/sonar/batch/index] is not valid: [403]
..So I ran using  org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar  then its working in locally and displaying the results.Where as through VSTS private agent its throwing the above error what I put in the top.

Comment: What's the detail code of pom.xml?

Comment: @starian chen-MSFT,I have shared in the one drive.@ https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvMxvVJdKJlVhx2mE9vbS6i-Lio3  I tried with another project as well.Throwing the same error.

Comment: @ starian chen-MSFT ,@ starian chen-MSFT,I am suspecting that its a proxy issue.My company proxy is not allowing VSTS proxy I guess.If you feel the same thing please let me know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: You said that it is working fine in local, does the local mean build agent machine?

Comment: Yes, local means the same build machine which I configured as private agent.

Comment: Yes, even if I run in local it's failing with different error if I give the goal as sonar:sonar. If I give goal as org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2: sonar it's publishing the results in localhost:9000

Comment: @starian chen-MSFT,Please respond to this.

Comment: What's the result if you run the failed command on the build agent manually? The command is:  C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C "C:\apache-maven-3.5.2\bin\mvn.cmd -f C:\agent\_work\1\s\ProductLinkWebCommon\pom.xml help:effective-pom"

Comment: @Eddie Chen - MSFT ,If I run this command locally: C:\apache-maven-3.5.2\bin>mvn.cmd  C:\agent_work\1\s\ProductLinkWebCommon\pom.xm
l help:effective-pom..Please find the below error: [ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'C' in the current project and in the plugin
groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the reposito
ries [local (C:\Users\pydimrd\.m2\repository), central (http://arltesp03.corp.bat
.com:8081/artifactory/plugins-release), snapshots (http://arltesp03.corp.bat.co
m:8081/artifactory/plugins-snapshot)] -> [Help 1]

Comment: [ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundF
orPrefixException

Comment: @PRAVEEN Sorry, I miss a "\\" in the command. Can you try with: C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C "C:\apache-maven-3.5.2\bin\mvn.cmd -f C:\agent\\_work\1\s\ProductLinkWebCommon\pom.xml help:effective-pom". And you can get the detailed command from your build logs.

Comment: @Eddie Chen - MSFT, If I give C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C "C:\apache-maven-3.5.2\bin\mvn.cmd -f C:\agent\_work\1\s\ProductLinkWebCommon\pom.xml help:effective-pom then build is succeeding in the local machine which is configured as private agent.

Comment: I just run this same command using cmd task in VSTS build def its failing with the same error where as in local its succeeding .The command is: C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C "C:\apache-maven-3.5.2\bin\mvn.cmd -f C:\agent_work\1\s\ProductLinkWebCommon\pom.xml help:effective-pom

Comment: Error is:  Scanning for projects...
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-plugins/28/maven-plugins-28.pom
Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:3.0.0: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:3.0.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:3.0.0
Downloading from central:

Comment: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.6/maven-resources-plugin-2.6.pom
Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6

Comment: @PRAVEEN Does the issue occur if you use Hosted Agent? And is your build agent configured to use proxy?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165021/discussion-between-praveen-and-eddie-chen-msft).

Comment: @starian chen-MSFT,Will you please respond to this?

Comment: @starian chen-MSFT,Will you please respond to this?

Comment: Can anyone please respond to my issue?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the reason of this issue.

Comment: Can anyone please respond to my issue?